# Splitting an RDD to get RDDs of subtypes

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like to be able to split an `RDD[T]` into RDDs of subtypes of `T`. What would be the best (most efficient) way to go about this? For simplicity (and as is possible in my case) assume that `T` is not generic itself.

The solution I've been going with is

```
implicit class RichRDD[U : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[U]) extends Serializable {
    def filterType[T <: U : ClassTag]: RDD[T] = rdd flatMap { case t: T => Some(t); case _ => None }
}
```

Then I persist the initial RDD and call `filterType` for all subtypes I'm interested in.

It seemed to me that `rdd.filter { classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance }.asInstanceOf[RDD[T]]` should have been a more efficient body for `filterType`, but when I used that I ran into some very peculiar problems (casting exceptions, which suggests the filtered RDD didn't contain the expected subtype - yet taking the `toString` dispatched to the right subtype method).

Does anyone have a more efficient/cleaner solution?

Comment: What details can you share about the specific types in the RDD? What's their common ancestor?

Comment: Shouldn't matter. I want the method to remain generic.